# Combine multiple command into single command

Tags: macros

I would like to combine the following four line into one command:

```
\tolerance=9999
\emergencystretch=10pt
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=100
```

My new command name should be `myhyp`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\myhyp}{%
  \tolerance=9999
  \emergencystretch=10pt
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
  \exhyphenpenalty=100
}
```

Note that the only need for such a command would be to set multiple times, or something that may change based on the scope. Otherwise, setting the individual elements once would be sufficient.

Comment: I would like to use it multiple times.